# how to parse following JSON data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new on JQuery. I have this JSON response from the server how could I parse it?

```
[
    {
        "note": {
            "created_at": "2012-04-28T09:41:37Z",
            "updated_at": "2012-04-28T09:41:37Z",
            "text": "aaaaaaaaaaafdafasd fasfasd dfa sdfasf asdfa fasdfda",
            "lng": 44.5159794497071,
            "id": 7,
            "deleted": false,
            "user_id": 1,
            "note_type": "text",
            "lat": 40.1884140543842
        }
    },
    [ ... more JSON ...]
]
```

How could I parse this?

Comment: that is not JSON format.

Comment: That's not properly formatted JSON, it looks more like a PHP array.

Comment: This is not JSON. Try to [validate](http://jsonlint.com/) it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the data type of the request to "json", and the data will be already parsed in your success callback.

Everything you need to know at the moment is on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Here is a very simple example of what you can do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, // the service URL. Must answer proper JSON
    data: {  // the parameters of the request. This should be adapted to your case
        param1: value1,
        param2: value2
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(resultData) {
        // here, resultData is your parsed json
    },
    error: function() {
        // handle error here
    }
});
```

Comment: I've already read this report. I don't imagine how to this. Could you tell me more specificly, writing some codes

Comment: @fish40 Example added ! Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Use this jQuery method to parse JSON objects.

Comment: This is ok, but after an ajax request, it's simpler and more compact to use the builtin ability to parse json in $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

If the server outputs actual JSON (the example in the question has errors) and it has the correct content type (`application/json` rather then the `text/html` that PHP defaults to) then you don't need to do anything.

jQuery will parse it for you (and present you with a JavaScript object in the success handler).

Answer (score 0):

That's *not* JSON. What you have posted looks like a PHP array that had brackets wrapped around it to try to make it into JSON.

Use [this site](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON in the future.

Now, to get your PHP array into JSON, use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) and dispatch it to the browser with a specific header.

```
$array = array( 'test' => 'sure' );
header('Content-type: application/json');
print json_encode($array);
exit;
```

Now, you'll have actual JSON with which you can use in JavaScript.

```
$.get(  'yourFile.php',
        function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
);
```